# spring tests with version spring 3.2.0 fails: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, maven, spring-test

My Maven-based project in Eclipse is trying to test a simple spring container with one bean inside, but the tests always fail:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
            at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Here you can see my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>springtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <spring_version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring_version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring_version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring_version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It follows my Spring application context (very simple):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean id="customer" class="com.company.test.beans.Customer">
    <property name="name" value="Axel Acker" />
    <property name="id" value="01" />
  </bean> 
</beans>
```

And finally here comes the test that does not work:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class TestCustomer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void testXAutoApplicationContext() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Customer customer = (Customer) applicationContext.getBean("customer");
        Assert.assertNotNull(customer);
        System.out.println(customer.getName());
    }
}
```

Yes, the context file is placed on the correct site: src/resources/applicationContext.xml

[eclipse project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXtgh.png)

With Spring 4.2.0 all tests are fine, but I have to get on with Spring 3.2.0.
Does anybody know how to handle this issue?

Kind regards,
Kladderradatsch

Comment: Can you share code via github

Comment: Unfortunately not. I do not have an account for GitHub.

Comment: Are you running this with Java 8?

Comment: Yes, Java 8 is in use.

Comment: So try updating to the latest 3.2.x release of Spring, they integrated some support for Java 8 starting from 3.2.9

Comment: What the heck? ... I changed to 1.7 and now it works. Your hint Tome, was essential. Do you know the reasons for that?

Comment: See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11656 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11719. I would suggest to either upgrade to Spring 4 or use latest 3.2.x instead of using Java 7 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the issue: wrong java version. It might solve the problem. In maven config  it says  source and target 1.8

So you should use java 7 or upgrade to Spring 4.

Change source and target to 1.7

Thanks @kladderradatsch
After updating Spring newer version of Java JDK should be used.

Comment: You are totally right! That's the solution! Thanks a lot all!

Comment: After I upgraded to spring version 3.2.16.RELEASE now JDK 8 can be used.